# is there any chrome plugin can start local process

Tags: google-chrome

I want to have a plugin that can start my local process, is there any existing solution available? The plugin should be able to accept parameters and the start the local .exe file properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Plugins execute in a sandbox that does not allow access to executing programs in the local filesystem.